# How to get selected child nodes as well as the parent node in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have some xml-like data returned from a query:

```
 <table>
 <tr linetype="data" linenum="1">
  <td colnum="c0">Balanced</td> 
  <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="24">24</td> 
  <td colnum="c2">Allocation</td> 
  </tr>
 <tr linetype="data" linenum="2">
  <td colnum="c0">Equity</td> 
  <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="27">27</td> 
  <td colnum="c2">Allocation</td> 
  </tr>
 <tr linetype="data" linenum="3">
  <td colnum="c0">Fixed Income</td> 
  <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="23">23</td> 
  <td colnum="c2">Allocation</td> 
  </tr>
 <tr linetype="data" linenum="4">
  <td colnum="c0">High Yield Bond</td> 
  <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="25">25</td> 
  <td colnum="c2">Allocation</td> 
  </tr>
 <tr linetype="data" linenum="7">
  <td colnum="c0">Aggregate Bonds</td> 
  <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="73">73</td> 
  <td colnum="c2">Asset Category</td> 
  </tr>
 <tr linetype="data" linenum="8">
  <td colnum="c0">Asian Equity</td> 
  <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="101">101</td> 
  <td colnum="c2">Asset Category</td> 
  </tr>
 <tr linetype="data" linenum="9">
  <td colnum="c0">Balanced</td> 
  <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="83">83</td> 
  <td colnum="c2">Asset Category</td> 
 </tr>
</table>
```

The child nodes can be grouped by column c2="Allocation" or "Asset Category". How can I select all `<tr>` where column c2="Asset Category", without losing the parent `<table>` tag?

Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rwdf0dnx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use jquery [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) like:

```js
$("table tr td[colnum='c2']").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == "Asset Category";
}).parent().css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr linetype="data" linenum="1">
    <td colnum="c0">Balanced</td>
    <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="24">24</td>
    <td colnum="c2">Allocation</td>
  </tr>
  <tr linetype="data" linenum="2">
    <td colnum="c0">Equity</td>
    <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="27">27</td>
    <td colnum="c2">Allocation</td>
  </tr>
  <tr linetype="data" linenum="3">
    <td colnum="c0">Fixed Income</td>
    <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="23">23</td>
    <td colnum="c2">Allocation</td>
  </tr>
  <tr linetype="data" linenum="4">
    <td colnum="c0">High Yield Bond</td>
    <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="25">25</td>
    <td colnum="c2">Allocation</td>
  </tr>
  <tr linetype="data" linenum="7">
    <td colnum="c0">Aggregate Bonds</td>
    <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="73">73</td>
    <td colnum="c2">Asset Category</td>
  </tr>
  <tr linetype="data" linenum="8">
    <td colnum="c0">Asian Equity</td>
    <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="101">101</td>
    <td colnum="c2">Asset Category</td>
  </tr>
  <tr linetype="data" linenum="9">
    <td colnum="c0">Balanced</td>
    <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="83">83</td>
    <td colnum="c2">Asset Category</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**References**

[**.parent()**](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: I found this the best answer. But I can't "up" this without enough points. Thanks to all contributions!

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
$("table tr td:contains('Allocation')").closest("tr").addClass("active");
```

This will select all tr with the td that contains allocation. I add the class active but you can do what ever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
var trs = $("td[colnum=c2]")
    .filter(function (x, i) { return $(i).html() === 'Asset Category'; })
    .map(function (x, i) { return $(i).parent()[0]; });
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vf91ynod/).

Answer (score 0):

I used this to remove the rows that were not "Asset Category" rows. you could easily modify this to hide or simply change the style of those rows if that is what you needed. Also, you could easily change this to read in the table from a different source than the page itself. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L76qpggp/1/)**

```
var mytable = [];
var rows = $('table').find('tr');

for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if(rows.eq(i).find('td[colnum="c2"]').text() == "Asset Category") {
       mytable.push(rows.eq(i));
    }
}

$('table').html("");
for(var j = 0; j < mytable.length; j ++) {
    $('table').append(mytable[j]);
}
```

Alternatively, you may want to read in the table data from another file (like an XML file).
This version mock imports the table and evaluates it starting from a string of table data. **[Alternate DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L76qpggp/5/)**

```
var tablestring = '<table><tr linetype="data" linenum="1"><td colnum="c0">Balanced</td> <td colnum="c1" rawvalue="24">24</td><td colnum="c2">Allocation</td></tr>...</table>';

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( tablestring );
var $xml = $( xmlDoc );

var mytable = [];
var rows = $xml.find('tr');

for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if(rows.eq(i).find('td[colnum="c2"]').text() == "Asset Category") {
       var temprow = document.createElement("TR");
       temprow.innerHTML = rows.eq(i).html();
       mytable.push(temprow);
    }
}

var newtable = document.createElement("TABLE");
$newtable = $( newtable );

for(var j = 0; j < mytable.length; j ++) {
    $newtable.append(mytable[j]);
}

$('body').append($newtable);
```